# How can I Reset the Width in CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having a problem with some new CSS due to an update of our plugin. The page in question is here: https://www.renophil.com/event/ghostbusters-in-concert/

Basically from the title below the image down to the share icons should be a left column. Then the description that starts with "Kick off your Halloween weekend..." should be a larger right column.

We are using Wordpress and Visual Composer. The left column uses the class of `vc_col-sm-4` and the right uses `vc_col-sm-8`. These are set to have the correct widths and work on mobile devices.

```
.vc_col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
}

.vc_col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
}
```

The problem is that the plugin we use for the events (The Events Calendar) has this CSS rule:

```
.tribe-events-single>.tribe_events>:not(.primary,.secondary,.tribe-events-related-events-title,.tribe-related-events) {
    order: 1;
    width: 100%;
}
```

which is overriding the width of my columns mentioned above. I thought I could fix it with `width:auto` but it didn't work. Is there a way to cancel it or do I have to add !important to the `.vc-col-sm-4` and `.vc-col-sm-8` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding specificity to the classes controlling the widths when that overriding events class is present. This should help get you in the right direction.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
     .tribe-events-single > .tribe_events .vc_col-sm-4 {
         width: 33.33333333%;
     }
     .tribe-events-single > .tribe_events .vc_col-sm-8 {
         width: 66.66666667%;
     }
 }
```

Comment: This one worked best for my purposes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The CSS rule:

```
.tribe-events-single>.tribe_events>:not(.primary,.secondary,.tribe-events-related-events-title,.tribe-related-events) {
    order: 1;
    width: 100%;
}
```

has a greater DOM precision and has priority. You can use `!important` as you said:

```
.vc_col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333% !important;
}

.vc_col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666666% !important;
}
```

or add `Additional CSS` from the theme preview mode and target the id element #tribe-events-content

```
div#tribe-events-content div.vc_col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%%;
}

div#tribe-events-content div.vc_col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666666%;
}
```